# How to transform a byte value "b'27 '" into int 27

Tags: python, arduino, int, byte

How to get the number in a byte variable ?

I have to transfer data from Arduino to Raspberry Pi with serial and python. I succeed to isolate the variable but its type is bytes, how to get this into an int variable ?

The variable is

```py
b'27'
```

but i want to get

```py
27
```

I tried

```py
print(int.from_bytes(b'\x27', "big", signed=True))
```

But i don't succeed to get the correct number 27

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `decode` to get it to a regular `str` and then use `int`:

```py
x = b'27'

y = int(x.decode()) # decode is a method on the bytes class that returns a string
type(y)
# <class 'int'>
```

Alternatively:

```py
y = int(b'27')
type(y)
# <class 'int'>
```

Per @chepner's comment, you'll want to note cases where weird encoding can break the latter approach, and for non-utf-8 encoding it could break both

Comment: Seems to me like `int(x)` works just fine without the need to decode, am I missing something?

Comment: I added that into my answer in the interest of completeness

Comment: `int(x)` fails if `x` isn't a simple ASCII encoding; consider `x = '१'.encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: @chepner for this *specific* use case `int(x)` works, but otherwise, yes, you'll want `decode` beforehand. Though if you don't know the encoding ahead of time you're back to square one anyways

Answer (score 1):

To supplement the helpful and practical answer given by `C.Nivs`, I would like to add that if you had wanted to use `int.from_bytes()` to retrieve the value 27, you would have needed to do:

```
int.from_bytes(b'\x1B', "big", signed=True)
```

because `'\x27'` is actually the hex value for the value 39. There are loads of [conversion tables](https://ascii.cl/conversion.htm) online that can be helpful for cross-referencing decimal against hex values. These two forms are only 1:1 for values less than 10.

Comment: Finally it was the wrong way because the Arduino sensor return 27 as humidity % but when I receive the variable in python it becomes b'27'

Comment: Good catch, I didn't even notice the change from `b'27'` to `b'\x27'` on the convert from bytes